# Minesweeper in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, minesweeper

I have written Minesweeper in JavaScript. Using OO-Approach.

`Cell` class describes a cell in the grid.

`Cell.t` property tells whether the cell is a mine or not.

`Cell.count` property stores the number of mines in the cell's vicinity.

`Cell.state` property stores whether the cell is used / unused / flagged.

`Grid` class provides an abstraction from the game's flow.

My main concerns are `Grid.init` and `Grid.click` functions.

`Grid.init` assigns the number of mines in a cell's vicinity to `Cell.count`.

`Grid.click` recursively clears out the neighbor cells (without mines) when a cell is clicked.

The conditions in `Grid.init` and `Grid.click` seem quite redundant. Is there any way to fix that? Is there any other change that I should make to improve the code.

```js
function Cell(type) {

  if (!(this instanceof Cell)) {
    throw new Error("Invalid call to constructor");
  }
  this.t = type;
  this.count = 0;
  this.state = 1;
}

function Grid(length, width, mines) {

  var i, j, rc, rr;
  if (!(this instanceof Grid)) {
    throw new Error("Invalid call to constructor");
  }
  this.l = length;
  this.w = width;
  this.m = mines;
  this.grid = [];
  for (i = 0; i < this.l; i += 1) {
    this.grid.push([]);
    for (j = 0; j < this.w; j += 1) {
      this.grid[i].push(new Cell("n"));
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < this.m; i += 1) {
    rr = parseInt(Math.random() * this.l);
    rc = parseInt(Math.random() * this.w);
    if (this.grid[rr][rc].t === "n") {
      this.grid[rr][rc].t = "m";
    } else {
      i -= 1;
    }
  }
}

Grid.prototype.init = function() {

  var i, j, n;

  for (i = 0; i < this.l; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < this.w; j += 1) {
      n = 0;
      if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0 && this.grid[i - 1][j - 1].t === "m") {
        n += 1;
      }
      if (j - 1 >= 0 && this.grid[i][j - 1].t === "m") {
        n += 1;
      }
      if (i + 1 < this.l && j - 1 >= 0 && this.grid[i + 1][j - 1].t === "m") {
        n += 1;
      }
      if (i - 1 >= 0 && this.grid[i - 1][j].t === "m") {
        n += 1;
      }
      if (i + 1 < this.l && this.grid[i + 1][j].t === "m") {
        n += 1;
      }
      if (i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < this.w && this.grid[i - 1][j + 1].t === "m") {
        n += 1;
      }
      if (j + 1 < this.w && this.grid[i][j + 1].t === "m") {
        n += 1;
      }
      if (i + 1 < this.l && j + 1 < this.w && this.grid[i + 1][j + 1].t === "m") {
        n += 1;
      }
      this.grid[i][j].count = n;
    }
  }
};

Grid.prototype.click = function(i, j) {


  this.grid[i][j].state = 0;

  if (this.grid[i][j].t === "m") {
    return 0;
  }

  if (this.grid[i][j].count === 0) {
    if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0 && this.grid[i - 1][j - 1].state === 1) {
      this.click(i - 1, j - 1);
    }
    if (j - 1 >= 0 && this.grid[i][j - 1].state === 1) {
      this.click(i, j - 1);
    }
    if (i + 1 < this.l && j - 1 >= 0 && this.grid[i + 1][j - 1].state === 1) {
      this.click(i + 1, j - 1);
    }
    if (i - 1 >= 0 && this.grid[i - 1][j].state === 1) {
      this.click(i - 1, j);
    }
    if (i + 1 < this.l && this.grid[i + 1][j].state === 1) {
      this.click(i + 1, j);
    }
    if (i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < this.w && this.grid[i - 1][j + 1].state === 1) {
      this.click(i - 1, j + 1);
    }
    if (j + 1 < this.w && this.grid[i][j + 1].state === 1) {
      this.click(i, j + 1);
    }
    if (i + 1 < this.l && j + 1 < this.w && this.grid[i + 1][j + 1].state === 1) {
      this.click(i + 1, j + 1);
    }
  }
  return this.check();
};

Grid.prototype.check = function() {

  var i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < this.l; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < this.w; j += 1) {
      if (this.grid[i][j].t === "n" && this.grid[i][j].state) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 2;
};
```

Note: I haven't provided the code which links these functions as event handlers to forms controls.

Answer (score 1):

I think your algorithms are OK. But there is room for improvement:

### Naming

One letter variable names are seldom useful. If you have to explain what `Cell.t` means, it isn't clear enough, it should be `Cell.type`. The same goes for `Grid.l, Grid.w and Grid.m`.

Also, the limited values for the variables should also be meaningful:

- I'm guessing "n" is "nothing" Or you could pass and "m" is "mine" but is a lot better to spell it out.
- The same goes for the states
- And I still don't understand what the `2` returned by `check()` means.

JavaScript doesn't have enums, you can use constants, but a full string (like "mine" instead of "m") should improve the code a lot (it still will be difficult to change in the future).

### Setting the mines

The current algorithm has an infinite worst case: if the cell randomly chosen keeps hitting a mine, it wouldn't end.

I think a good alternative could be to generate an array of `length * height` with as many `true`s (or another meaningful value) as `mines`, shuffle that array, and then use that as the grid.

<sup>I don't know if you can shuffle a bidimensional array, but shuffling a one-dimension array and then converting to 2-dimension should be easy.</sup>

### Neighbors

In order to simplify the `init()` and `click()` functions, you could make a `neighbors()` function in `Grid` and then iterate over these.
  Something like this:

```
Grid.prototype.neighbors = function(i, j) {
  neighbors = []
  if (i - 1 >= 0 && j -1 >= 0) {
    neighbors.push(this.grid[i - 1][j - 1]);
  }
  ...
  return neighbors;
}
```

And then, in `init()`:

```
n = 0;
for (neighbor in this.neighbors(i, j)) {
  if (neighbor.type == "mine") {
    n++;
  }
}
this.grid[i][j].count = n;
```

And in `click()`:

```
for (neighbor in this.neighbors(i, j)) {
  if (neighbor.state === 1) {
    this.click(neighbor.x, neighbor.y);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Grid.click()` returns 0 if the user has clicked on a mine, otherwise, it returns `Grid.check()` which returns 1 if user has not clicked on all the non-mine cells or 2 if user has clicked on the non-mine cells (has won the game).

Comment: How do I implement `Grid.click()` using `Grid.neighbors()` (the one you mentioned)? Since, `Grid.click()` needs to be called with the index of the cell in the grid, the cell needs to be aware of its index. I have implemented it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sann/qz0y55e8/). Note that, now the `Cell` class has stores the index in `Cell.x` and `Cell.y`.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya I've added an example for `click()`.